# Allow Youtube video embeds

Tags: feature-request

Per this request: [Provide a way to embed videos in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66397/provide-a-way-to-embed-videos-in-answers)

I often create screencasts to suppliment answers and would love for the youtube.com link to embed itself into the answer.

Examples:

- [add value to shipping service](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129693/add-value-to-shipping-service/130514#130514)
- [How do I do per-item shipping based on the number of products?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125948/how-do-i-do-per-item-shipping-based-on-the-number-of-products/130350#130350)

Answer (score 5):

I do not think video would add any value to the site.

One, on a technical site like this, I don't think they add much to the answer.  Just having a video would be the equivalent of a link-only answer.  The video would have to be "transcribed" anyway.

Two, we are one of the prime spam targets on the Stack Exchange network, and I deal with a lot of spam.  I see this as being abused way too easily.

Comment: I linked to the "See Also" in your response at the very beginning. Maybe it would be abused too much. Not sure on that end. I think it would be extremely helpful. Drupal has interface and video is one of the easiest ways to teach and share how to use that interface. Other Stack Exchanges have opted to allow video embedding, I'm just asking for others to weigh in before it gets completely ignored.

Comment: Sorry for repeating the link.  Didn't notice it was a dup after I had searched for other discussions on MSE about this.